# In visualStudio cant find all the properties of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

This is a question about how to use Visual Studio to find out what the properties and methods of an object are - to help figure out how to use the object.

In the image below, in the watch window I can see all the properties of `v2` including `IsExpanded`. However when I type a 'dot' the intellisense pops up with a different set of properties (and if I try to use `v2.IsExpanded` in my code I get an error).

Please can you keep the answer worded simply. (I'm not sure its a bug or I'm being ignorant.)

(I have also posted the code for my project (its a WPF app) but I dont think its relevant.)

[image: intellisense]

```
<Window x:Class="ObjElements1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TreeView Name="Tree1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.1"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.2">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.2.1">
                        <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.2.1.1">daslkjdlak</TreeViewItem>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.2.1"></TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tree1.3"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace ObjElements1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var v2 = Tree1.Items[0];



            //var v3 = v2.IsExpanded;
            //var v3 = v2.IsExpandedProperty;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Have you tried `x:name`? Sometimes that works for me instead.

Comment: Thanks @Bonzo. I gave it a try - no improvemt though I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliSense doesn't know what type the items in Tree1.Items are - they are all stored as objects. If you want to access the properties of an object stored there, you'll have explicitly cast them out of Object like this:

```
MyType v2 = (MyType)Tree1.Items[0];
v2. (...)
```

Where MyType is the actual type of Tree1.Items[0].

Addendum: 
Best practice when dealing with a collection of objects you don't have full control over (some other component or method could add/remove something from Tree1), you should verify the type before you try to brute force it into a particular type. Either way works:

```
MyType v2 = Tree1.Items[0] as MyType;
if (v2 != null) {    
    //Do something
}
else {
    //Error
}
```

Or:

```
if (Tree1.Items[0] is MyType) {
    v2 = (MyType)Tree1.Items[0];
    //Do something...
}
else {
    //Error
}
```

The first approach has the benefit of only calling the Items[] indexer once.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I didnt understand why the watch window was saying that `v2` was type `System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem` but it wouldnt let me create a variable of this type. Anyway casting worked.

Comment: The Visual Studio watch window pulls some reflection shenanagins to determine the details of objects. You can do the same thing in your code via functions like GetType(). Even before you cast it, the object IS a TreeViewItem, but it's stored in an object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WPF. In general, Visual Studio could not display intellisense for object.

[image]

In your case, `Tree1.Items[0]` is an object. If you want intellisense, you need to cast it to appropriate object first.

For example,

[image]

***Note:*** `Tree1.Items[0]` might not be `TreeViewItem`, because I do not know WPF TreeView. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: And this is why I've always been against `var`!

Comment: It is not about var keyword. `var v2 = Tree1.Items[0] as TreeViewItem;` will also display intellisense.

Comment: OK. but when you have to give it the real type, you won't get confused like what happened to this buddy.

Comment: Thanks very much - that worked, and my understanding has just gone up a notch!

Answer (score 0):

You must remember that c# is typed at compiletime. And at that time it its type is Object.
When you look at runtime you see the current type that is in Tree1.Items[0], but for the compiler it could be any type that is an Object and he permits any Method and Property not defined on Object.